# Google now won't read the contents of lists

Tags: google, google-now, accessibility

Google now won't read the contents of the lists add in the following two screenshots.

[image]
[image]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>

This is completely unusable from the point of view of blind users, who may want to compose a text, e.g. am impersonal or asynchronous one add opposed to a phone call, and know the list contents which are currently not read out.

Is there a fix for now? Do newer Google devices fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Google Talkback Installed and activated?  This utility is meant specifically to help blind users interact with Android.  If you have not installed, configured, and tried out Talk back yet I highly suggest it for the visually impaired.  It installs as an accessibility service so it can be run system wide, and you should still be able to utilize whatever other methods you are already comfortable with while adding this one to hopefully help fill in holes like this one.

Talk Back Info Page: http://www.androidcentral.com/what-google-talk-back